# RichMarker: attach click event listener to a marker array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my code block where I `push` `RichMarkers` into the array:

```
// Populate markers array
for (let i = 0; i < FOUND_OBJECTS_TEST.length; i++) {

    let richMarker = new RichMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(FOUND_OBJECTS_TEST[i].latitude, FOUND_OBJECTS_TEST[i].longitude),
        map: mainMap,
        draggable: false,
        flat: true,
        anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
        content: `<figure class="marker_place" data-id="${FOUND_OBJECTS_TEST[i].id}"><img src="svg/map/ic_cat_${FOUND_OBJECTS_TEST[i].type}.svg"><figcaption class="marker_place_caption">${FOUND_OBJECTS_TEST[i].caption}</figcaption></figure>`,
    });

    markers.push(richMarker);
}
```

How can I also attach a `click` event listener to each marker, so, that when it will be clicked I'd have got this marker's `data-id` value?

**EDIT**
I can add `event listener` to the markers like this:

```
// Populate markers array
for (let i = 0; i < FOUND_OBJECTS_TEST.length; i++) {
    let richMarker = new RichMarker({
           .....
         });

    google.maps.event.addListener(richMarker, 'click', function(event) {
        let id = $(this).data('id'); // returns undefined
        console.log(`clicked on marker ${id}`);
        console.log(this);
    });

    markers.push(richMarker);
}
```

But I can't get marker's `data-id`... it logs `clicked on marker undefined`.

Comment: This problem is solved in the duplicate question: [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) with function closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the data-id as a property of the `marker`, then retrieve it in the click listener function using `this`.

```
// Populate markers array
for (let i = 0; i < FOUND_OBJECTS_TEST.length; i++) {
  let richMarker = new RichMarker({
     marker_id: FOUND_OBJECTS_TEST[i].id,
       .....
     });

  google.maps.event.addListener(richMarker, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log(`clicked on marker `+ this.marker_id);
    console.log(this);
  });

  markers.push(richMarker);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This works. I was unaware that I can add custom properties to the RichMarker class.

Answer (score 0):

```
k =  markers.push(richMarker);

google.maps.event.addListener(markers[k-1], 'click', function (event) {
                    // you code eg:
                    alert('ok');
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. But what `markers[k-1]` does? P.S. Please look at the updated question.

Comment: markers[k-1] is the content of the array of markers ...  is the object that have the listener .. .. every time you push an object in an array you get the related index .. in this way you can directly related to this object what do you need  ... in your case bind a litener to the object ..